# Prevent from changing the values in array

Tags: java, arrays

In my program I am creating an array which contains values of year-month-date. I assign them the values 2019, 6 and 17. As of now, the program allows me to change the value (see the comment in main). But i do not want this to be possible, how can i prevent this?

```
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Date date = new Date (2019, 6, 17);
        date.printDate ();

        int[] dateValue = date.getDate ();
        dateValue[2] = 35; //Changes the value from 17 to 35. Is not suppose to happen.

        date.printDate ();
    }
```

```
public class Date
{
    private int[] ymd = new int[3];
    public Date (int year, int month, int day)
    {
        ymd[0] = year;
        ymd[1] = month;
        ymd[2] = day;
    }

    public int[] getDate ()
    {
      return ymd;
    }

    public void printDate ()
    {
        System.out.println (ymd[0] + "-" + ymd[1] + "-" + ymd[2]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change `getDate()` to return a copy of the private array instance variable:

```
public int[] getDate ()
{
  return Arrays.copyOf(ymd,ymd.length);
}
```

This way callers of the method cannot mutate the state of the `Date` instance by modifying the returned array.

Comment: To elaborate a little on this: It's just like returning an object with public setter methods. If you give someone direct access to your Object, and that Object let's anyone use setter methods, than anyone can change your Object at any time. 

You can get around that by returning a copy, as suggested, or by using a different object which doesn't have public setters, or is immutable.

Comment: Note that [all arrays have a type-safe public clone method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7), so `return ymd.clone();` will work as well.